# Polymer globals attributes something strange

Tags: polymer, global

in my test, i have 3 elements imported from the main html file :

```
    <html><head><title>my-app</title>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="elements/app-globals.html">
    <link rel="import" href="/Polymer/my-app/elements/my-categories.html">
    <link rel="import" href="/Polymer/my-app/elements/my-items.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <my-categories></my-categories>
    <my-items></my-items>
  </body>
</html>
```

with 'app-globals.html' being:

```
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name="app-globals" attributes="data selectedCategoryId selectedItemId">
    <script>
    (function() {
    var values = {};
    Polymer('app-globals', {
        ready: function() {
            console.log("app-globals -> ready");
            this.values = values;
            console.dir(this.values);
        },
    });
    })();
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

'my-categories.html':

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="/Polymer/my-app/elements/app-globals.html">

<polymer-element name="my-categories">
  <template>
    <app-globals id="globals"></app-globals>
    <div>selectedCategoryId = {{$.globals.values.selectedCategoryId}}</div>
    <ul>
      <template repeat="{{category in categories}}">
        <li class="li-category" data-_id="{{category._id}}" on-tap="{{selectCategory}}">{{category.name}}</li>
      </template>
    </ul>
  </template>
  <script>
  Polymer('my-categories', {
    values: {},
    ready: function() {
      var HOST = 'xxx.yyy.zzz.www';
      var PORT = '8888';
      this.categories = <loaded from websocket>;
    },
    selectCategory: function(event, detail, sender) {
      var elt = (event.target.nodeName == 'INPUT')? event.target.parentNode : event.target;
      this.values.selectedCategoryId = elt.dataset._id;
      this.$.globals.values.selectedCategoryId = elt.dataset._id;
      return false;
    }
  });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

here when one of the li element is clicked the 'selectedCategoryId' is updated.

this value is passed thru globals to the last element 'my-items.html':

```
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="/Polymer/my-app/elements/app-globals.html">

<polymer-element name="my-items">
  <template>
    <app-globals id="globals"></app-globals>
    <style>
    </style>
    <div >selectedCategoryId = {{$.globals.values.selectedCategoryId}}</div>
    <ul>
      <template repeat="{{item in items}}"
                on-category-tap="{{handleCategoryTap}}">
        <li class="li-item" data-_id="{{item._id}}" on-click="{{selectItem}}">{{item.title}}</li>
      </template>
    </ul>
  </template>
  <script>
  Polymer('my-items', {
    values: {},
    ready: function() {
      var HOST = 'xxx.yyy.zzz.www';
      var PORT = '8888';
      console.log("'my-items' -> this.$.globals.values:");
      console.dir(this.$.globals.values);
      for(var prop in this.$.globals.values) {
        if(this.$.globals.values.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
          console.log("this.$.globals.values[" + prop + "] = " + this.$.globals.values[prop] + "");
        }
      }
      console.log("'my-items' -> this.$.globals.values.selectedCategoryId = " + this.$.globals.values.selectedCategoryId);
    },
    handleCategoryTap: function(event) {...,
    selectItem: function(event) {...}
      return false;
    }  });
  </script>
```

resulting in something strange to me :
console.dir(this.$.globals.values) give me the correcte respons:
Object {
    selectedCategoryId: "547dfb6578be56f6630041a8"
}

However selecting this attribute 'selectedCategoryId' results with:
console.log("'my-items' -> this.$.globals.values.selectedCategoryId = " + this.$.globals.values.selectedCategoryId);
gives me:
'my-items' -> this.$.globals.values.selectedCategoryId = undefined
 undefined why ?

Comment: I believe the omitted part of your code in the given example have significance on the problem you are facing. And I don't think in the given example `console.dir(this.$.globals.values);` will print `Object { selectedCategoryId: "547dfb6578be56f6630041a8" }` since at that point the `this.$.globals.values` yet received the value.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use: https://github.com/akc42/akc-meta

I did use it to share info across the DOM with local data binding!

See my project if you want a working example: https://github.com/MeTaNoV/firebase-element-extended